# Making https calls with intel.xdk

Tags: rest, ssl, intel-xdk

We're trying to make a call to our .NET REST api which uses a SSL certificate. We have set the server headings to Allow All (using CORS) and it works great when we try to reach it via a web browser with the below code, but when we try with an application created with the Intel XDK all we get are errors (shown in pictures below the code):

```
function test1() {
    var self = this;

    self.ajax = function (uri, method, data)
    {
        alert('sending: ' + data);
        var request = {
            url: uri,
            type: method,
            contentType: "x-www-form-urlencoded",
            accepts: "application/json",
            cache: false,
            origin: 'localhost',
            data: data, 
            success: function (result)
            {
                console.info("WORKS!");
            },
            error: function (jqXHR) {
                console.log("Got a response");
                console.log(jqXHR);
                console.log("ajax error " + jqXHR.status);
            }
        };
        return $.ajax(request);
    };

    self.ajax(
            'https://localhost:44301/token',
            'POST',
            'grant_type=XXX&username=XXX&password=XXX'
            )
            .done(function (data) {
                alert('got data from auth');
                alert(data.access_token);
            });
}

function test2()
{
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://localhost:44301/token",
        type: "POST",
        jsonp: "callback",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        data: "grant_type=XXX&username=XXX&password=XXX",
        crossDomain: true, //Don't think this is required really...
        jsonpCallback: function (data)
        {
            console.log("JSON P CALLBACK!");
            console.info(data);
        },
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
}
```

[image]
[image]

In the Intel XDK project we use the **xhr.js** file which seems to be the universal solution to this problem every where but I haven't seen anyone actually use it in combination with SSL certificates.

Comment: does the server have a valid SSL certificate?

Comment: @krisrak: Yes, as I said, this works well everywhere else, just not in an Intel.XDK app.

Comment: can u try opening xdk in command line using this option `--ignore-certificate-errors`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to have been a simple content encoding issue. After adding a header setting the content encoding to UTF-8 it worked:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://localhost:44302/api/ping',
    type: 'POST',
    beforeSend: function (request)
    {
        //This part
        request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
    },
    dataType: "json",
    data: JSON.stringify("Hello")
})
.done(function (result)
{
    console.info(result);
});
```